# Is it possible with an ADF ComboBox component to type in values not present in the given LOV?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am working on an input form using ADF. I have an input field in which I want to show a list from which the user can select the value and also require a type option in case the value user want is not in the list.

I use the JDeveloper 12.2.1.3 for development. I have tried using ADF ComboBox component based on a static list. The component gives a list a expected. But I cannot type in a new value in case the value I wanted is not in the list. I can only type whatever is in the list already.

I am looking for something similar to the HTML input-datalist combination which gives a list and allows type if the intended value is not in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InputListOfValues and other LOV components only allow you to enter data which is present in the list. That is the way these components are designed. It would not make sense to allow other input as you normally use such components in places where you want to make sure the user can only input reference data defined in other data.

Anyway, it's easy to create some kind of component which allows you exactly what you want. I wrote a blog n this here https://tompeez.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/jdeveloper-11-1-1-6-0-afinputtext-with-self-made-look-up-not-using-lov/

Answer (score 0):

From [this page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/documentation/adf-faces-rc-demo-083799.html) you can download and run the ADF Faces Rich Client Demo, which shows all components and what they do.